# Поиск центра окружности с максимальным кол-вом вхождений точек в нее

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, вычислительная-геометрия

> На вход программе подается кол-во рандомных точек (N) и радиус окружности (R). Нужно найти координаты центра окружности радиусом R так, чтобы в окружности было максимальное кол-во точек.

Вообще нет идей как реализовать это.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Простой кубический (`O(n^3)`)алгоритм:

- перебрать пары точек
- если расстояние между ними не превышает `2*R`- построить две окружности, проходящие через обе точки (одну для случая `Dist=2R`)
- посчитать количество точек внутри окружности

Почему это работает - если существует окружность, включающая `Max` точек, то её можно подвигать так, чтобы ничего не вылезло наружу, а пара (или больше) точек оказалась точно на окружности, и наоборот.

Существует метод, работающий за `O(n^2logn)` на основе углового заметания(sweep)/сортировки по углу

Comment: Крутой ответ! Я прямо в восторге от того, что Вы написали про второй - оптимизированный - способ!